# ANDROID CANGOBACK not working as it was supposed to work

Tags: android, webview

I m writing an app with webview in which i have hyperlinks in it.when i go to a hyperlink i can't go back to my main site with my back key. 
here is my webview code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

   private WebView webView;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    /*------------enable javascript--------------- */
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    /*-------------------------------------------- */


    /*------------enable Zoom--------------- */
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    /*-------------------------------------------- */
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    /*------------size of the webpage in webview--------------- */
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    webView.setInitialScale(40); // 0 - 100 where 100 is full scal
    /*-------------------------------------------- */


    /*------------call url ------------------------ */
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.gr");   
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() );
    /*-------------------------------------------- */


}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && !( webView.canGoBack() ) ){
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.gr");
        return false;
    }

 else if (webView != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack() ) {
 webView.goBack();
return false;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: try this `if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
   webView.goBack();
   return true;
  }`. When you click back button it should go to previous page

Comment: i ve tried that...See i m writting an app for advertisment site..when the user "hits" a banner he is redirecting in the banners site..When he is in the banner site and he preesses the back key it doesnt redirect him in my main site...i ve made it before but i lost the code..:(

Comment: Hey @stef14, I know it's long time question had been asked but I am facing same problem. Can you please suggest the solution if you found out?